# Passing more objects with eventhandler

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I was reading similar questions about overloading eventhandlers by not using eventhandlers but delegates or by calling other functions from within the eventhandler. But I really can't see how I can bind the delegate to the custom control like I am binding ButtonClick in the code below. I have a form with let's say 10 custom controls. Each custom control has 5 buttons. The way I am passing the key presses from each button of each custom control is:

**This is in my custom control's cs file (GlobalDebugMonitorControl.cs)**

```
namespace GlobalDebugMonitor
{
public partial class GlobalDebugMonitorControl : UserControl
{
    public GlobalDebugMonitorControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public event EventHandler ButtonClick;

    private void MultiControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ButtonClick != null)

            this.ButtonClick(sender, e);//**How Do I put here both sender and this**
    }



}
}
```

Then all the buttons in the custom control.designer.cs have something like this:

```
this.openFileBTN.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MultiControl_Click);
this.editFilePathBTN.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MultiControl_Click);
this.delControlBTN.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MultiControl_Click);
this.addControlBTN.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MultiControl_Click);
this.editCompanyNameBTN.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MultiControl_Click);
```

**And then in my form1**

```
namespace GlobalDebugMonitor
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        protected void UserControl_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Button tempButton = (Button)sender;
            GlobalDebugMonitorControl tempParentControl = (GlobalDebugMonitorControl)((tempButton.Parent).Parent).Parent;

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string item in tempGlobalPaths)
            {
                    GlobalDebugMonitorControl tempGDMcontrol = new GlobalDebugMonitorControl();
                    tempGDMcontrol.Name = item.Split(',')[0];
                    tempGDMcontrol.companyNameLBL.Text = item.Split(',')[0];
                    tempGDMcontrol.globalPathTXT.Text = item.Split(',')[1];
                    tempGDMcontrol.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl_ButtonClick);
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tempGDMcontrol);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

As you can see I create a tempButton by the sender to do some things based on which button was pressed of the 5 and by sender.parent.parent (the custom control is inside a table that is inside a flowlayout that is inside another panel etc)I finally reach the custom control that tells me which of the 10 custom controls had it's button pressed.

So the question is, is there a way to pass both the sender(button that was pressed) and the great grandfather (the custom control that owns the sender button)? I mean it works but this way I need to now how many "generations" I need to go up.

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding it, but you could use lambdas and closures when assigning the handler: `tempGDMcontrol.ButtonClick += (sender, args) => UserControl_ButtonClick(sender, args, tempGDMcontrol);` And update `UserControlButtonClick` to take 3 parameters `void UserControl_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args, object grandfather)` And perhaps I have the "grandfather" wrong, it it might be this instead: `tempGDMcontrol.ButtonClick += (sender, args) => UserControl_ButtonClick(sender, args, this);` But maybe this is on the right track to help you.

Comment: Can you show the code where you choose what to do based on which button was pressed? I want to see what makes one button different from the other 4.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I've made some edits in my original post in an effort to make things a bit clearer. My problem is in GlobalDebugMonitorControl.cs and in this.ButtonClick(sender, e);. How can I pass both sender and this? Maybe I am being thick, but I really can't see it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I would do it simply with an if. If tempButton.name =="openFileBTN" then do something, if tempButton.name == "editCompanyNameBTN" then do something else and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could introduce your own type of EventArgs

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public GlobalDebugMonitorControl Control { get; set; }

        public CustomEventArgs(GlobalDebugMonitorControl control) 
        {
            this.Control = control;
        }
    }
```

and then change eventHandler to use it:

```
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> ButtonClick;
```

so the calling code would be:

```
this.ButtonClick(sender, new CustomEventArgs(this));
```

and of course the implementer of the event:

```
protected void UserControl_ButtonClick(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
        {

            Button tempButton = (Button)sender;
            GlobalDebugMonitorControl tempParentControl = e.Control;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The only thing extra was that I had to change the tempGDMcontrol.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl_ButtonClick); to tempGDMcontrol.ButtonClick += new EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>(UserControl_ButtonClick);